# pip Installation Error for installing channels

Tags: python, django, pip

When I run this code

```
sudo pip install channels
```

I've got this error:

```
running build_ext
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/twisted
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/twisted/test
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-MLq5fN/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
src/twisted/test/raiser.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that there is some package missing in your system.

Try to install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

If it does not work, try this:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libssl-dev
```